# Has ec2 made self-hosting possible for 'amateur' sysadmins possible?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm a developer, and it seems ec2 has made it possible for a amateur sysadmin like me to setup and maintain a fairly large set of servers.

Now I don't mean to undermine real sys admins, as I know the value of them but what I am trying to get at is that someone like me can setup and maintain a cluster of servers (front end web servers, with some db servers) using tools like ec2 and capistrano with the help of google.

Now this isn't something I would do as a long term thing, but as a startup, one-man operation, I think I can pull this off until business takes off and I can hire this important role out.

With ec2, I get my firewall, so I basically open up port 80 on my public facing server, which will run haproxy and route requests to my cluster of servers.

Ofcourse I am simplifying the setup, but just want a feel for what you guys think about my perception.

My application is a web application, that will be runing Ruby on rails (passenger) and talking to mysql or postgresql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EC2 (and all the other VPS players in the market) certainly lowers the barrier to entry in several ways.

- Capex is no longer needed for equipment purchase, and there are no separate MRC for bandwidth/power/cooling
- No hardware to maintain or fix
- Scaling is stupid simple - very little lag between increased load and when you're able deploy more systems

That said, even with a VPS, someone with at least a moderate working knowledge of systems administration is still needed for things like patching, securing, and keeping watch over your servers, and making sure that the OS and underlying infrastructure is as ready as it can be to host your application. Sure, as a one-man operation, you *may* be able to keep watch over your servers *and* fulfill the rest of your job responsibilities, but maybe not. You're the only one that can decide that. If you're confident that you can keep all the balls in the air (and not have your servers crash, taking down your app), then by all means, go for it. If you have a doubt in your mind, though, it may be very worth your time to at least consult with someone who has had experience in this sort of thing to make sure that you put your best foot forward as you're getting infrastructure set up.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe, clouds like AWS not only lowers the entrance barrier but also allows one IT pro to manage servers of multiple clients. Thus allowing more IT consultants to emerge.

Nevertheless, clouds are not very mature right now. Some solutions should be worked-out to make cloud setups secure and cost-effective.